# Getting GPSTool icon back on manage layers tool bar of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

The GPS Tools icon has vanished from the "Manage Layers" tool bar and I would like to get it back.

I have tried removing and re adding the tool bar but that did not work and I know that I can access it from Vector -> GPS (but I keep forgetting ;)

Hmm... I think it must have gone when I upgraded to QGIS 2.18.2

Comment: I tried Joseph's script but that did not help so I tried upgrading to 2.18.7.  Hopefully 3.0 will fix whatever I have broken.

Answer (score 1):

If the *GPS Tools* plugin is enabled, we could try to make it visible in the toolbar by using the following code in the **Python Console**:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction): 
    if '&GPS Tools' in x.text():
        x.setVisible(True)
```